# Images not being loaded into webpage

Tags: html, image, .htaccess

Images are located in /www/images

They are not loading into the page. Not sure why.

My .htaccess file contains the following(I believe the issue is here):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This gets rid of the .php and adds a trailing slash. When it is not present, images load. When it is present, they do not.

**I would like to keep these settings, but be able to load images.**

**HTML**

```
<img src="images/imagename">
```

EDIT: I am positive it is an issue with my .htaccess file.

Comment: Just tried it, and the issue remains the same. I believe it is an issue with my .htaccess file. Whenever I don't include it, all images load with no issues.

Comment: Have you tried to add the image extension at the end? `<img src="images/imagename.png" />`

Comment: @VladimirJovanović Yes, I have it added currently.

Comment: Browser's developer tools like "Network" and "Inspector" will probably give you a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it out this way `<img src="http://www.example.com/images/imagename">`
Or use the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you! You solved the issue. I implemented both solutions and it seems to have worked. There is a trailing slash, no extension, and the image is displayed. I will have to update my database to include this to make it easier to call upon these images.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below your html head tag `<base href="http://www.examle.com" />`

Comment: Tried this out, issue still persists. I believe it has to do with my .htaccess.